# alert sometimes work sometimes doesn't work in JS

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a problem with Javascript. I have a database. I query my database to a form. I reference id to JS function(like this show_modal();).  When I click button function works but sometimes doesn't work? Why? Sometimes alert shows the value of functions sometimes nothing does.

HTML

```
<div class="product-card--body">
 <div class="card-image">
  <img photourl"]?="" src="&lt;?=$value["/>
  " alt=""&gt;
  <div class="hover-contents">
   <a class="hover-image" href="product-details.html">
    <img photourl"]?="" src="&lt;?=$value["/>
    " alt=""&gt;
   </a>
   <div class="hover-btns">
    <a class="single-btn" href="cart.html">
     <i class="fas fa-shopping-basket">
     </i>
    </a>
    <a class="single-btn" href="wishlist.html">
     <i class="fas fa-heart">
     </i>
    </a>
    <a class="single-btn" href="compare.html">
     <i class="fas fa-random">
     </i>
    </a>
    <a class="single-btn" data-target="#quickModal" data-toggle="modal" href="#">
     <i class="fas fa-eye" id="get_arr_id" onclick="show_modal(&lt;?=$value[" productid"]?="">
      ); "&gt;
     </i>
    </a>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
function show_modal(id){
    var sendData = new FormData();
    sendData.append("id", id);
    alert(id);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Click on an `a` tag can be conflict with `onclick` event on an `i` tag.

Comment: OH, My GOD. Thanks Bro.